# getting "Class not found: org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ant.AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter" in eclipse 3.8

Tags: eclipse, pde, ajdt

i have been successfully using ajdt in conjunction with pde headless build in eclipse 3.6. i have the following entries in project's **build.properties**:

> compilerAdapter=org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ant.AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter
>   sourceFileExtensions=*.java, *.aj

however, once i switched to eclipse 3.8, i have been getting the following stack during my ant-based pde headless build:

> [java]
>   c:\eclipse3.8\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.0.v20120523-1555\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml:43:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java]
>   c:\eclipse3.8\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.0.v20120523-1555\scripts\build.xml:105:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java]
>   c:\eclipse3.8\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.0.v20120523-1555\templates\headless-build\customTargets.xml:12:
>   The following error occurred while executing his line:
>
> [java]
>   c:\eclipse3.8\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.0.v20120523-1555\scripts\productBuild\allElements.xml:20:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java]
>   c:\eclipse3.8\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.0.v20120523-1555\scripts\genericTargets.xml:119:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java]
>   c:\eclipse3.8\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.0.v20120523-1555\scripts\genericTargets.xml:129:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java]
>   c:\MyApp\temp\compile.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.xml:4:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java] c:\MyApp\temp\plugins\com.foo.myplugin\build.xml:176: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> [java] c:\MyApp\temp\plugins\com.foo.myplugin\build.xml:122: **Class
>   not found: org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ant.AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter**

please help me. thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that AJDT is not installed in your build eclipse.  It needs to be around in order for the AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter class to be found.

Comment: no, its installed. i can see it on the welcome screen, under new projects, etc.

Comment: one more thing, Andrew. while i was able to locate the source file in org.eclipse.ajdt.core.source plugin, i could NOT locate the class in org.eclipse.ajdt.core plugin. the same goes for eclipse 3.6, so i am quite sure that it is ok. my question is where does eclipse actually obtain the class from?

Comment: Deleted my last comment since it was incorrect.  Inside of your org.eclipse.ajdt.core_xxx.jar there should be a nested jar called ajc_compiler_adapter.jar.  This is where the class file is located.

Comment: Are you running a headless build?  If so, just be aware that your build eclipse is not necessarily the same as your target environment.  AJDT must be installed in the build eclipse (but not necessarily in the target environment).  There's not much more I can suggest without seeing your build.xml file and your customTargets.xml file (you can paste them above).